# Connect to shh using a Putty generated ppk key on Mac OSX

Tags: mac, ssh

I have a .ppk key generated by putty. How can i convert that to a public/private ket to use it with ssh on mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PuTTYgen's *Export to OpenSSH* command, which will output the keypair in PEM format usable by OpenSSH.

Both private and public keys are in the same file. If you want to extract the public key, use `ssh-keygen -yf mysshkey > mysshkey.pub`, but that is not required.